# Simple function to classify NA values

Tags: r, function

I have tried to find an answer to what appears to be a simple question but without any success.

I want to create a function which would operate on different variables for different data frames. All that the function needs to do is search for the value "don't know" and replace it with NA. I would do this manually as follows:

```
raw.df$S8[raw.df$S8 == "Don't know"] <- NA
```

As an exercise in learning R I would like to do this by function but cannot find a way to reference the inputs to the function.

In this example code I cannot even create a vector which is a copy of the dataframe variable I want to recode - it is coming out as NULL. So until I know how to do this part, I can't progress to recoding values as NA.

```
> NADK <- function(df,x) {
+  DDD <<- df$x
+ }
> 
> NADK(raw.df, S8)
> DDD
NULL
```

I am assuming that I cannot use the commands df$x and expect r to know that this is coming from the function inputs?

Comment: Use `[` or `[[` for subsetting instead of `$`

Comment: In addition, It is better not to use `<<-` and based on the function, you may require quote for 'S8'

Comment: @docendodiscimus - you mean I should use df[x]? In this case I get the error Error in `[.data.frame`(df, x) : object 'S8' not found but it is definitely there.

Comment: @akrun - I must have misunderstood an article - I thought I needed <<- to ensure that the vector is available outside of the function?

Comment: Please take some time to read through `help("[.data.frame")`. `$` extraction is only used in interactive mode.

Comment: Creating objects in the global enviroment from inside a function can have some problems.  Instead it is better to assign `DDD <- NADK(data, 'S8')`

Comment: @docendodiscimus  and akrun thank you for your comments. The use of $ and [] is a little clearer, but I still have problems getting the outcome I want. If I want to reproduce this raw.df$S8[raw.df$S8 == "Don't know"] <- NA then my line of function is   df[x][df[x] == "Don't know"] <- NA ?? and my function call DDD <- NADK(raw.df, 'S8') - in this case my total output DDD is NA

Comment: Could you please provide a small example data and better describe the problem, so that we can run it to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing a function which hardwires in `"Don't know"` it seems more flexible to have that as an argument to the function. Something like:

```
to.na <- function(df,x,na.string){
  df[x][df[x] == na.string] <- NA
  df
}
```

This returns the altered dataframe.

For example, if

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Larry", "Curly", "Moe"),BirthYear = c(1900, 1910, 1920), DeathYear = c("1950", "1960", "Not dead"))
```

So that `df` is

```
   Name BirthYear DeathYear
1 Larry      1900      1950
2 Curly      1910      1960
3   Moe      1920  Not dead
```

Then:

```
> df <- to.na(df,"DeathYear","Not dead")
> df
   Name BirthYear DeathYear
1 Larry      1900      1950
2 Curly      1910      1960
3   Moe      1920      <NA>
```

If you are reading the dataframe from a file by using `read.table` (or associated functions like `read.csv`) then you might be able to avoid the problem to begin with by using the parameter `na.strings`. See `?read.table` for details.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want, and you are right - having the NA string in the function is good idea. The only addition I made was to add droplevels(df[x])

Comment: Clean solution, +1 for encouraging to not hard-wire a specific string.

Although I'm most impressed about how you [brought Moe back to life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe_Howard)!